# Dispatch_queue loading large image memory problem

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, queue

I'm facing some problem loading a large image on iPad. The image size is 1024x748, landscape mode.
I have several galleries with different image for every gallery. For better performance and to synchronize the interface with the loading, I have create a dispatch queue.
When the user press a gallery I add to the queue a series of operation of loading image and store the UiImageView resulting in an array, without adding it to the subview. After that i manage the presentation of each image in a Scrollview.
If the user press a button and scroll the gallery I can see, after a short time, that the memory used to load the image is released.
If I continue to change the gallery the memory increase, and I receive a memory warning, and the application crash.
I know that's the queue that release all the transitory images in a certain moment, but I don't know how to force them to release all the memory in a very short time.
I also tried with NSAutoreleasePool without success.